# Not able to launch kinect on turtlebot ROS fuerte , turtlebot ISO install

Tags: kinect, turtlebot, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I installed the turtlebot from the ISO supplied by iheartengineering. I am able to run the keyboard teleoperation but unable to launch the kinect to view on the rviz.

I configured everything properly, the installation automatically detected the IP and assigned to the turtlebot. When I run

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch
```

I got

```
turtlebot@turtlebot:~$ roslaunch turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch
... logging to /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/935ee6ec-18f7-11e2-bafc-002163c42ffd/roslaunch-turtlebot-25851.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://turtlebot:41913/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /kinect_laser/max_height
 * /kinect_laser/min_height
 * /kinect_laser/output_frame_id
 * /kinect_laser_narrow/max_height
 * /kinect_laser_narrow/min_height
 * /kinect_laser_narrow/output_frame_id
 * /openni_launch/debayering
 * /openni_launch/depth_frame_id
 * /openni_launch/depth_mode
 * /openni_launch/depth_registration
 * /openni_launch/depth_time_offset
 * /openni_launch/image_mode
 * /openni_launch/image_time_offset
 * /openni_launch/rgb_frame_id
 * /pointcloud_throttle/max_rate
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES
  /
    kinect_breaker_enabler (turtlebot_node/kinect_breaker_enabler.py)
    kinect_laser (nodelet/nodelet)
    kinect_laser_narrow (nodelet/nodelet)
    openni_launch (nodelet/nodelet)
    openni_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    pointcloud_throttle (nodelet/nodelet)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_breaker_enabler-1]: started with pid [25877]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[openni_manager-2]: started with pid [25878]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
[ INFO] [1350547767.989473252]: Initializing nodelet with 2 worker threads.
process[openni_launch-3]: started with pid [25900]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[pointcloud_throttle-4]: started with pid [25928]
[ INFO] [1350547768.076326059]: [/openni_launch] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [25944]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [25963]
[ INFO] [1350547769.100903910]: [/openni_launch] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[kinect_breaker_enabler-1] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/935ee6ec-18f7-11e2-bafc-002163c42ffd/kinect_breaker_enabler-1*.log
[ INFO] [1350547770.121378299]: [/openni_launch] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1350547771.141588971]: [/openni_launch] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1350547772.153494951]: [/openni_launch] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1350547773.170691697]: [/openni_launch] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1350547774.189712549]: [/openni_launch] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1350547775.201424931]: [/openni_launch] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
^C[kinect_laser_narrow-6] killing on exit
[kinect_laser-5] killing on exit
[pointcloud_throttle-4] killing on exit
[openni_launch-3] killing on exit
[openni_manager-2] killing on exit
[ INFO] [1350547775.993898334]: [/openni_launch] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[openni_manager-2] escalating to SIGTERM
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

I tried to check whether the kinect is detectable from USB
so I ran the `lsusb` and found

```
turtlebot@turtlebot:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0458:0007 KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 045e:02c2 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 045e:02be Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 045e:02bf Microsoft Corp.
```

I see 3 microsoft Corp message so the kinect is fine and getting power. The Irobot is fully charged and the kinect green light is blinking.
Then I thought may be the openni package is not installed so I tried to reinstall the openni ros fuerte package and it says

```
turtlebot@turtlebot:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-openni-camera ros-fuerte-openni-launch
[sudo] password for turtlebot: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ros-fuerte-openni-camera is already the newest version.
ros-fuerte-openni-camera set to manually installed.
ros-fuerte-openni-launch is already the newest version.
ros-fuerte-openni-launch set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I read some of the replies on the same issue and tried

```
turtlebot@turtlebot:~$ killall XnSensorServer
XnSensorServer: no process found
turtlebot@turtlebot:~$ XnSensorServer
Starting sensor server...
Running...
^C
```

One more thing I am using the kinect for windows and not xbox360 kinect.
Now I am new to ROS and dont know what to do next. Please help me with this problem so that I can start with building some maps and do SLAM.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46151/not-able-to-launch-kinect-on-turtlebot-ros-fuerte-,-turtlebot-iso-install/) by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2012-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is almost certainly related to your Kinect for Windows.  As far as I know, it is still really not supported very well on Linux, and certainly not using standard binaries from ROS repositories.  The only chance you'd have would be to run modified source code for the Kinect drivers.  If you are interested in doing this, check out @GermanUser and @PatrickMihelich on [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/12876/kinect-for-windows/).

Can you obtain/borrow a standard Xbox Kinect to test on?

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2012-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on 2012-10-18**:
thank you so much ... I have been frustrated trying to make it work. I need to get the xbox kinect now..